# Are two Broadcast Receivers (one Alarm Manager and another for System Events) required?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am calling the following `BroadcastReceiver` using `AlarmManager` every X mins. Its working fine.

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (CommonFuncs.isConnectedBySettings(context)) {          
            if(CommonFuncs.isUpdateTimeValid(context)){                
                Intent intentCurSvc = new Intent(context, CurrencySvc.class);
                context.startService(intentCurSvc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name=".service.AlarmSvcRecevier"
        android:process=":remote" >
    </receiver>
```

I want to use the same `BroadcastReceiver` for connectivity change as well, by just adding the following manifest.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".service.AlarmSvcRecevier"
        android:process=":remote" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But my receiver is not getting called when WIFI is connected. I am not sure what is the problem. Do I need a separate receiver for `AlarmManager` and `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` to perform same operation? Is my approach correct?

Comment: Try this intent `android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE` to see if it works

Comment: I did try it , but its still not calling the receiver.